# Moving Twitter Boostrap site from development to production – Compiling LESS to CSS

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I’ve been developing a Bootstrap site locally using the supplied less.js file.  This has been working great. I’m now looking at how to deploy a complied CSS file to the production server. I’m on Windows 7 locally and have had reasonable success with these programs:

http://winless.org/

http://crunchapp.net/

So I’ve compiled a style.css file and am linking to this in my PHP / HTML files.  An odd thing that I’ve noticed is the styles don’t work when I remove the line of code linking to less.js

So even though I’m using CSS rather than LESS, my pages still require to be linked to the less.js compiler. Does anyone know why this is?

I’ve been searching for a tutorial on deploying Twitter Bootstrap sites (with compiled CSS from LESS) but have been unable to locate something.  Any links would be greatly appreciated. I’m now wondering if Bootstrap sites reply on users having JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post a link to your work somewhere? or some code?
There should be no reason for the css to not work after the less.js call has been removed.

Let me have a look at the code for you and see if i can spot any oddities.

Comment: Doh.  No sooner do I post and I've found the problem.  I was linking to my compiled stylesheet using rel="stylesheet/less" instead of rel="stylesheet".  I'd never noticed the /less before.

All sorted!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I made the same mistake myself just last week. Easily done.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to remove the less.js dependency would be to compile your CSS on the server before you release. To do this, you need to have Node.js installed, and then [follow these instructions](http://lesscss.org/#-server-side-usage) to install Less for Node.

Then, if you go down to the "command-line usage" section you can see how to use the `lessc` command to compile your Less files down to CSS files.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a few options.  Also found http://blog.dotsmart.net/2010/11/26/running-the-less-js-command-line-compiler-on-windows/